# Xamarin.Forms how to align button text to the right

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am using **Xamarin.Forms**,I need text be aligned to the right on `Button` Control.

```
  var FirstNameButton = new Button { Text ="First Name "};
```

Any Idea ?

Comment: HorizontalTextAlignment doesn't work?

Comment: not working with button (on label working fine )

Comment: HorizontalOptions="End" ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I use Grid very often and I believe it is a good option to achieve what you want:

```
        <Grid Grid.Column="0" BackgroundColor="{Binding DeleteButtonBackgroundColor}" Padding="5,0,0,0" ColumnSpacing="0">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <ColumnDefinition Width="5*"/>
          <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <Label Grid.Column="0"
                 x:Name="LabelDeleteSelectedExamsPartOne"
                 Text="{Binding DeleteButtonText}"
                 TextColor="White"
                 FontSize="{Binding CustomFontSizeMedium, Source={x:Static constants:DeviceInfo.Instance}}"
                 HorizontalOptions="Start"
                 VerticalOptions="Center"/>

          <Label Grid.Column="1"
                 x:Name="LabelDeleteSelectedExamsPartTwo"
                 Text="&#xf014;"
                 Style="{StaticResource LabelStyle}"
                 FontSize="{Binding ExamPageBigIcon, Source={x:Static constants:DeviceInfo.Instance}}"
                 FontFamily="FontAwesome"/>   

        <Grid.GestureRecognizers IsEnabled="{Binding DeleteButtonIsEnabled}">
          <TapGestureRecognizer
              Command="{Binding DeleteSelectedExamsCommand}"/>
        </Grid.GestureRecognizers>
      </Grid>
```

Comment: But the labels don't react when you tap as happens with a button.

Comment: hi @IanWarburton I can't remember this detail now but if you want to you can change the label color after tap or put an activity indicator.

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to do this (as opposed to the accepted answer) is to use a custom renderer (in this case, the `ButtonRenderer` class) to override the default behavior of the `Button` view in every individual platform specific projects.

The following is an example pertaining to the Android platform:

```
[ExportRenderer(typeof(Button), typeof(ButtonCustomRenderer))]
class ButtonCustomRenderer : Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.ButtonRenderer {
     protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.Button> e) {
         base.OnElementChanged(e);
         Control.Gravity = GravityFlags.End // Set the horizontal text alignment to right 
                            | GravityFlags.CenterVertical; // Set the vertical text alignment to center
     }
     public ButtonCustomRenderer(Context context) : base(context) { } // To merely use the suggested constructor as the default one is deemed obsolete
}
```